# How to plot after doing a groupby on pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have a time series data which contains date, year, month and ratings columns. I have grouped by year and month and and then i am counting the number of rating in each month for that year. I have done this the following way:

```
nightlife_ratings_mean = review_data_nightlife.groupby(['year','month'])['stars'].count()
```

I get the following data frame

```
year  month
2005  8           3
      9           4
      10         16
      11         13
      12          7
2006  1          62
      2          24
      3          13
      4          20
      5          11
      6          13
      7          11
      8          29
      9          33
      10         46
```

I want to plot this such that my x label is year and and y label is count and i want a line plot with marker-ø. 
How can I do this. I am trying this for the first time. So please help.

Comment: what do you mean by a line plot with marker-ø?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `plot` on your DataFrame and include the option `style = 'o-'`:

```
plt = nightlife_ratings_mean.plot(x = 'year', y = 'stars', style = 'o-', title = "Stars for each month and year")
plt.set_xlabel("[Year, Month]")
plt.set_ylabel("Stars")
```

This will plot the following:

[image]